# How to change MPEG2-ts without encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

I have many ts file for apple streaming ( MPEG2-TS format ). Can I change, for example PTS/PCR params for this files, using ffmpeg ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.

Have a look at [the setpts filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#asetpts_002c-setpts).  Their slow-motion example would look like this using the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mpg -vf setpts=2.0*PTS out.mpg
```

Comment: No. Unless you specify `-c copy` or similar, it will reencode.